# div to be hide on horizontal scroll with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I need a div to hide on body horizontal scroll
I apply the below code which is working fine on vertical scroll
how to apply the same code for bottom scroll ?

```
<script>
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                $('.nk-sidebar').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('.nk-sidebar').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var documentHeight = $(document).height();
  var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();

  if (scrollPosition + windowHeight >= documentHeight) {
    // Bottom scroll reached
    $('.nk-sidebar').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('.nk-sidebar').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I mean the vertical scroll , as its working fine with horizontal scroll